# What does event.waitUntil do in service worker and why is it needed?

Tags: javascript, promise, dom-events, service-worker

MDN suggests that you do the following to create and populate service worker cache:

```
this.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open('v1').then(function(cache) {
      return cache.addAll([
        '/sw-test/',
        '/sw-test/index.html',
        ... etc ...
      ]);
    })
  );
});
```

I do not understand that code. The `waitUntil` method is documented too, and it seems the code above is the single purpose of it's existence at the moment:

> The ExtendableEvent.waitUntil() method extends the lifetime of the
>   event. When called in an EventHandler associated to the install event,
>   it delays treating the installing worker as installed until the passed
>   Promise resolves successfully. This is primarily used to ensure that a
>   service worker is not considered installed until all of the core
>   caches it depends on are populated.

What I do not understand is:

- How does `waitUntil` generally affect code flow? Does it stop event from propagating until it's promise resolves?
- Why is it needed in the context of opening worker cache?

I am asking this question because I have problems with the code above and I would like to understand it.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

As the description says:

> the `ExtendableEvent.waitUntil()` method extends the lifetime of the event.

If you don't call it inside a method, the service worker could be stopped at any time (see [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/service-workers/#service-worker-lifetime)).

So, the `waitUntil` method is used to tell the browser not to terminate the service worker until the promise passed to `waitUntil` is either resolved or rejected.

About your specific questions:

- In the case of the `install` and the `activate` events, it delays the state switch of the service worker to `installed` and `activated` (see the [specification of the `waitUntil` method](https://www.w3.org/TR/service-workers/#wait-until-method), in particular the last part of the paragraph).
- I think the rest of my answer already answered as to why it is needed.

Comment: I still don't understand. If I remove the `event.waitUntil`, what will happen? I have tried to remove the `event.waitUntil`, it still worked fine. Cache Storage had cached resource and the page could be visited offline. If you need Demo, I can send it to you.

Comment: If you don't call it, the service worker COULD be stopped at any time. This doesn't mean it will be stopped, so in some cases it might work and in some cases (depending on timing) it will not work.

Comment: Yes, I had found what you said in the official document. What I want to know is:
1. How to trigger the "not working" cases?
2. Why the service worker could be stopped if I don't call it? The key point is Why, not What.

I could not find the answer in the document.

Comment: The service worker can be stopped because it uses resources. The browser tries hard not to waste resources, so if a worker is not needed anymore it might be killed. Another reason is stated in the document: if the service worker is operating abnormally (e.g. an infinite loop), clearly you want to terminate it.

Comment: Thanks for your patient explanation. You are right. But I find out anthor purpose for using `event.waitUntil`. With `event.waitUntil`, If any resource in `cache.addAll` fetch failed, the service worker could be stop.  Without `event.waitUntil`, the service worker will continue running even though some of `cache.addAll` fetch failed. I had tried and verified the theory. For more information: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/lifecycle#install

Comment: It's still the same reason. Without `event.waitUntil` the browser could be terminated at any point, even if the installation hasn't finished (no matter whether it's successful or unsuccessful). It keeps running without `event.waitUntil` in your example, but it's still a timing thing (you can't be sure the same behavior will happen to other people with different machines or to you with a future browser version).

Comment: The issue is that the install event may return before cache will be ready, because promise is async. Therefore we have to wait on the promise (until the cache will be ready).