# Service Worker -Why extend lifetime of event?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, google-cloud-messaging, service-worker

In this example:

```
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {
console.log('On notification click: ', event.notification.tag);
event.notification.close();

// This looks to see if the current is already open and
// focuses if it is
event.waitUntil(clients.matchAll({
type: "window"
}).then(function(clientList) {
  for (var i = 0; i < clientList.length; i++) {
    var client = clientList[i];
    if (client.url == '/' && 'focus' in client)
    return client.focus();
  }
  if (clients.openWindow)
    return clients.openWindow('/');
}));
});
```

`event.waitUntil()` is necessary for the function to properly work because it extends the events' lifetime. But why do you need it? Why can't the promise simply be resolved after event has returned?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does event.waitUntil do in service worker and why is it needed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37902441/what-does-event-waituntil-do-in-service-worker-and-why-is-it-needed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case we need `event.waitUntil` because `client.focus` and `clients.openWindow` are only allowed when called as the result of a notification click event (to protect users from windows opening without their permission). Without `event.waitUntil` you run the risk of the event returning before `clients.openWindow` or `client.focus` is called, in which case the browser will give you this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Not allowed to open a window.
```

See the answer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30302636/clients-openwindow-not-allowed-to-open-a-window-on-a-serviceworker-google-c) and the [openWindow reference on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clients/openWindow).

Comment: I already assumed that this could be the potential reason. Thank you for the conformation!